# iOS Parse: Add / Get array of PFUsers

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform

In my app, I have an playlist, which I want to share with another friend. In parse I save the Playlist objects and from the user which created the playlist i save the key: `@"user_id"`.

Now I changed Pointer _User to an array of Users for my sharing future. 
I already saved in `@"user_id"` column, an array of users (users which have access to the same playlist) :

```
[
  {
    "__type" : "Pointer",
    "className" : "_User",
    "objectId" : "teH3s20xxx"
  },
  {
    "__type" : "Pointer",
    "className" : "_User",
    "objectId" : "hgkcjHyi9T"
  },
  {
    "__type" : "Pointer",
    "className" : "_User",
    "objectId" : "K2dZTEKpIX"
  },
  {
    "__type" : "Pointer",
    "className" : "_User",
    "objectId" : "4dbmDuR6LF"
  }
]
```

Now I need to check if current user is using playlist mentioned above. How can I check if my user is an object in `@"user_id"` column array?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear with what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is first get the array from that column in parse. Then you want to traverse through it using a for in loop:

```
for(PFUser *user in arrayYouGotFromParse)
{

if(user == [PFUser currentUser])
//Current user is in the array

}
```